# Морфемный состав

Tags: морфемика

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти слова, которые соответствуют следующей схеме: приставка-приставка-корень.

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, ответ очень прост. Первое, что пришло в голову, - ПЕРЕРАСХОД. Правда, здесь есть нулевое окончание. Тогда можно взять наречия, например "вразлет, вразброс, вразнос" и подобные

Мне очень нравится определение этих процессов, данное уважаемым коллегой в ходе обсуждения вопроса, - театр абсурда. Такое впечатление, что некоторые лингвисты (я не имею в виду Вас, Ирма), пытающиеся защитить очередную бессмысленную и никому не нужную диссертацию,высасывают из пальца некоторые псевдотеории и пытаются придать им вид некоей научности. Какой нулевой суффикс?!!! Слово "зелень" возникло от прилагательного "зеленый" без прибавления каких-либо морфем. Произошло при этом только смягчение конечного "н". И, повторяю написанное ранее, это объяснение способа словообразования (словообразовательный разбор), а не морфемный анализ слова.

Comment: Виктор1799, почитайте тему.

Comment: А вот насчет наречий - это да! 
Хотя обычно такие задания рассчитаны на существительные...
С другой стороны, а почему не считать, что у наречий тоже нулевое окончание?

Comment: Уважаемый коллега! По Вашему совету я еще раз прочитал тему и не вижу необходимости придумывать какие-то экзотические иностранные слова. В русском языке полно неизменяемых слов (прежде всего наречий и деепричастий), которые вписываются в заданную схему. В наречиях и деепричастиях нет и не может быть никаких окончаний, в том числе и нулевого, потому что нулевое окончание, как я его понимаю,- это окончание, которого нет в данной форме, но оно появляется при изменении слова по падежам, числам, родам или лицам.

Comment: Такие наречия, как вразлёт, вразброс, вразнос тоже не подойдут, так как в них есть нулевой суффикс!

Comment: Что за нулевой суффикс? Не знаю таких. Я знаю, что слова "разнос, разброс" и т.п. образованы так называемым бессуффиксным способом, но это уже словообразовательный разбор, а не морфемный состав.

Comment: А бессуффиксный способ образования слова- это и есть нулевая суффиксация. И нулевой суффикс всё-таки принято выделять.

Comment: Ирма, это уже начинает слекга напоминать театр абсурда.
Почему тогда не признать, что у всех слов есть нулевой суффикс?
Даже там, где есть ненулевой, запишем ещё парочку нулевых?
Ну с окончаниями (И.п. ед. м.р. или там Р.п. мн. ж.р.) я ещё могу при некотор усилии воли понять разницу между нулевым окончанием и отсутствием оного в принципе. Но с суффиксом??? Оставаясь в здравом уме и твердой памяти - ну никак.

Comment: Попробую кое-что прояснить. Вот, например, как образовалось существительное зелень? Вы ответите: от прилагательного зелёный. Тогда будет уместен вопрос: а при помощи какой морфемы,ведь эти слова отличаются только окончаниями? И именно в этом случае слово образовалось при помощи нулевой суффиксации. Но это вовсе не значит, что во всех словах этот суффикс обязан присутствовать. И кстати, там, где уже есть суффикс ненулевой, нулевого уже быть никак не может.

Comment: Ирма, вы своим объяснением вы все запутали окончательно. 
Давайте от печки. Как отличить слово с нулевым суффиксом от слова без суффикса вообще? 

>И именно в этом случае слово образовалось при помощи нулевой суффиксации. 
Не вижу причин для такого подхода. А главное - он внутренне противоречив. Ну нельзя в самом деле ставить наличие суффикса от того, есть ли однокоренное слово с флексией? Т.е. в слово дурень по такой логике суффикс нулевой (есть дурной), а в трутень - нет? 
А для слова "пальто" есть "пальтовый".

Comment: И ещё я никогда не скажу, что зелень образовалось от "зелёный". В лучшем случае - от "зелен", да и то под огромным вопросом. Полные прилагательные - относительно молодая вещь в языке, а "зелень" восходит к праидоеврепейскому пласту. Если не ошмбаюсь, Оно родственно таким словас как золото, злак, зола... 

>И кстати, там, где уже есть суффикс ненулевой, нулевого уже быть никак не может.   

Простите, но тут на веру тиакие вещи не принимают. Доказывайте.
Два суффикса бывает? Плчему один из них (по вашей логике) не может быть нулевым?

Comment: Про нулевой суффикс знаю со студенческих лет, правда. в других случаях. например, в глаголах прошедшего времени:нёс, несла. несли. В мужском роде- нулевой суффикс. Он проявляется в других формах (так и с нулевым окончанием происходит).  В школе это понятие дается разве что в гуманитарных классах для детей, которые пойдут на филфак. Для школьников  ответ Виктора верен. Для современных студентов не знаю. Но судя по заданию, не все это нулевой суффикс признают.

Comment: Да дело в том, что мы сейчас в университете эту тему проходим и нам так даже преподаватель объяснял. Вы,Виктор, задайте запрос "нулевой суффикс" и почитайте, там всё аналогично изложено. Так что я вовсе и не пытаюсь кого-то запутать, просто хотелось узнать мнение других людей насчёт задания, а получилась дилемма по поводу существования или несуществования нулевого суффикса...

Comment: Спасибо, Ирма, за совет. Я еще вчера почитал о нулевом суффиксе, но все равно считаю это "изобретение" надуманным, ненужным, вносящим путаницу. Наша дискуссия об этом тоже свидетельствует

Answer (score 1):

В чем проблема?
Рас/с/каз - корень исторический - каз, от же в отказ, наказ и проч.
С - древняя приставка, рас - современная.

Сложности только в том, что считать корнем на современном этапе... Но это отдельный разговор.
~~~~~

> По такой схеме "приставка-приставка-корень" можно искать только неизменяемое слово.

Квазиполупальто не подойдет?

Придумал! *"**Подсубконто**"*.

Тоже марсианское, но программисты 1с его знают (не помню, знает ли сама 1с-ка).

Comment: А тогда какое это получается пальто?) Я не очень понимаю значение приставки квази.

Comment: Ну замените на "псевдо-"
Хрен редьки не слаще. Все равно слово марсианское.

Comment: Я думаю, что если этот задание из курса "Современный русский язык", то слово "рассказ" не подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

А как же нулевое окончание? По такой схеме "приставка-приставка-корень" можно искать только неизменяемое слово.

Comment: Да, это и усложняет дело)

Comment: Вряд ли... Вы слишком много от детей хотите.
И потом неизменяемые слова в русском - иностранные, в них обычно ьничего кроме корня и не выделяется. 
А откуда такая задачка-то?

Comment: Это задание для студентов 2 курса филологического университета. Мне пока на ум пришло только одно слово: суперультрахаки(цвет), но и оно не совсем удачное.

Comment: Тогда - извините. Это серьёзно. 
"Подсубконто" не подойдет?

"Суперультрахаки" интернет не знает.

Answer (score 0):

> [[@виктор1799](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799)](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799) Что за нулевой суффикс? Не знаю таких. Я знаю, что слова "разнос, разброс" и т.п. образованы так называемым бессуффиксным способом, но это уже словообразовательный разбор, а не морфемный состав.

Как это вы не знаете нулевых суффиксов. Классический пример: формообразующий суффикс Л у глаголов прошедшего времени, который отсутствует в глаголах нёс,  пёк и подобных. Что у них нулевое окончание, Вы же не будете отрицать. Придётся признать и наличие нулевого суффикса.

> ЦитатаТакие наречия, как вразлёт, вразброс, вразнос тоже не подойдут, так как в них есть нулевой суффикс!

А вот это уже мне непонятно. Я знаю, что формообразующие части слов могут быть нулевыми. Объясните, пожалуйста, здесь что происходит?